# C# checkboxlist with enum

Tags: c#, enums, checkboxlist

I have an enum:

```
enum Mangment{
ReportsManagment,
NormalUserManagment,
PowerUserManagment
};
```

Now, I want to create a checkboxlist and allow the user to chose from this 3 options, than i want to get the selection out back as an enum and process it.

This is my code:

```
private void saveB_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (object itemChecked in rolesPermissionsCBL.CheckedItems)
            {
                var permissionsName = itemChecked.ToString();
                ## How do i get the item checked as an enum..?
            }
         }
     }
```

Comment: ...winforms...wpf...asp.net...?

Comment: Please provide us with your attemps at making it work and explain how it's different from what you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Mangment enumValue = (Mangment)Enum.Parse(typeof(Mangment), itemChecked.ToString(), true)
```

Comment: I cant find Managment class, I only see System.Managment namespace. what reference am i missing?

Comment: @susparsy thats the enum you have created.

Comment: @susparsy `Mangment` is your `enum` type name. Not a class, replace it with your enum name

Comment: @RameshRajendran true is to ignore case.